# SpeechRecognitionEngine: UnloadAllGrammars is VERY slow

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm working with .NET (C#) and the speech recognition engine.  I'd like to be able to load and unload grammars as my state requires them.  Seems to me that this is a good way to limit the chances of getting a false positive; however, whenever I run UnloadAllGrammars() it takes almost a minute to complete sometimes.
Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that if I run SpchRecognizer.RecognizeAsyncStop() prior to UnloadAllGrammars() then there was no delay.  Don't know the guts of the speech recognizer, so I can't justify why this is needed; but at least empirically, that allows this to work.